# OpenCV function similar to matlab's "find"

Tags: matlab, opencv

I am looking for a function in openCV to help me make masks of images.

for example in MATLAB:

B(A<1)=0;

or

B=zeros(size(A));

B(A==10)=c;

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some functions allow you to pass `mask` arguments to them. To create masks the way you describe, I think you are after [Cmp or CmpS](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/core_operations_on_arrays.html#cmp) which are comparison operators, allowing you to create masks, by comparison to another array or scalar. For example:

```
im = cv.LoadImageM('tree.jpg', cv.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
mask_im = cv.CreateImage((im.width, im.height), cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1)
#Here we create a mask by using `greater than 100` as our comparison
cv.CmpS(im, 100, mask_im, cv.CV_CMP_GT)
#We set all values in im to 255, apart from those masked, cv.Set can take a mask arg.
cv.Set(im, 255, mask=mask_im)
cv.ShowImage("masked", im)
cv.WaitKey(0)
```

Original `im`:

[image]

`im` after processing:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

OpenCV C++ supports the following syntax you might find convenient in creating masks:

```
Mat B= A > 1;//B(A<1)=0
```

or

```
Mat B = A==10;
B *= c;
```

which should be equivalent to:

```
B=zeros(size(A));
B(A==10)=c;
```

You can also use `compare()`. See the following OpenCV [Documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#compare).

Comment: Would you have any idea why the result of (matrix == 1) would result in those values that are 1 in the source matrix being 255 in the output matrix?

Comment: OpenCV has concept called masking. The convention is that a binary mask is implemented using chars where 0->0 and 1->255. So the best answer is that 255 is retrned for no special reason other then convention. Note that when using a mask in OPenCV functions you don't have to stick to this convention. Any number between 1-255 is true and 0 is false.

Comment: Thanks!  Yes I realize 255 will evaluate as true, but in MATLAB it's common to add up the 1's in the binary matrix output.  I was confused that I was getting huge numbers because all were 255.  I'll keep that in mind.  Thanks again.

Comment: I agree that it can be inconvenient. You could mask it this way `A =& 0x1` in order to force it to 1.