# Equivalent of Matlabs "Find" function in opencv

Tags: c++, c, matlab, opencv, matrix

I am trying to convert a matlab code to Opencv Code.
 I need to convert the below code to opencv.
**I would like to know is there any equivalent of matlab find function in opencv.**

S has `(x,y)` data and size of S is `100x2`

```
ind = find(S(:,1) >= xm & S(:,1) <= xM & S(:,2) >= ym & Sm(:,2) <= yM);
Snew = S(ind,:);
```

**Edit:**
In the question [OpenCV function similar to matlab's “find”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597107/opencv-function-similar-to-matlabs-find), the output Snew and the input S are of same size, but here in my question, Snew is not of the same size as S.. For example:

```
S = [ 76    96
    26    55
    51    14
    70    15
    90    26]

ind = find(S(:,1) > 50);
Snew = S(ind3,:);

Snew = [ 76    96
    51    14
    70    15
    90    26]
```

As you can see, Snew and S are not of same size...

The im in the refered question is of the same size of initial input im...

Comment: @Donal Fellows I have edited my question

Comment: @Back in a Flash I have edited my question

Comment: @EdChum I have edidted my question and reason why its not duplicate.

Comment: indeed this question does not seem a duplicate to me, the title of the duplicate is misleading and its accepted answer does not answer this question.